# Blazor update UI inside component foreach loop

Tags: c#, blazor

I have Blazor components in a way similar to this:

**Main.razor**

```html
@foreach (Vehicle vehicle in _vehicles) 
{
    if (vehicle.Visible)
    {
        <VehicleComponent Vehicle=@vehicle></VehicleComponent>
    }
}

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized() 
    {
        _vehicles = new List<Vehicles>();
        // -> _vehicles being filled here
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

**VehicleComponent.razor**

```html
@if (Vehicle != null) 
{
    <img src="@(Vehicle.src)"/>
    <div id="@(Vehicle.Id)" tabindex="@(Vehicle.tabindex)">
        <h3>@(Vehicle.text)</h3>
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that all the `VehicleComponent`s inside the loop are rendered after the loop is finished. But I want the component to completely render, before the next List item will be rendered.

I tried using `StateHasChanged()` after each item in `Main.razor`, but I got an infinite loop.
Is there a way I can render each component in the loop after each other (and update the UI)?

Comment: Why? [comment too short]

Comment: @CorentinPane because we have a big system rendering a lot of components dynamically. And currently, the active screen refreshes its UI when the whole screen is done rendering, instead of per component.

Comment: That's no reason to update the UI inside a loop. Which isn't what the code you posted does anyway. If you want individual components to refresh themselves when a property changes, bind that property to a Parameter of the components. That's the only way the component can know that eg `vehicle.Visible` has changed

Comment: As for `rendered after the loop is finished.` what is the *actual* problem? That component is simple and shouldn't take long to render. Are you trying to render far more items than can be displayed? That's a bad idea and will cause serious performance and scrolling issues, no matter the framework. Use [component virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-5.0) instead to only render the visible rows

Comment: This isn't a Blazor issue - if you try to generate a `<table>` with 100K `<tr>`s, rendering and scrolling will take forever. Web sites use paging and virtualization to avoid generating HTML that can't be displayed

Comment: try to use `@key=...`

Comment: The problem is that you are populating your list in one synchronous operation, so the Main component only renders the list as a whole. If you want each vehicle to render in turn, don't populate the list like that - add each one and re-render after each vehicle is added - but as said by Ivan - make sure you use a `@key` on each `Vehicle` component you render - or you may end up with a performance nightmare.

Comment: @MisterMagoo In our case, the list is being retrieved as data packet, and a check to which component should be rendered (for example Car, Bike, Plane etc), with all types having their own components.

I added `@key`, and also tried using `<Virtualize>` instead of `@foreach`. Although indeed the render time is reduced, the components are not correctly rendered (the screen is flickering and doing weird stuff with the components)

Comment: If you use  Virtualize, you MUST make sure your template placeholder item matches exactly to the height of a rendered list item - if the list items vary in size, it's not for you.

Comment: @MisterMagoo hmm, all my objects use absolute width and heights, so I might actually be able to use this. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 6):

If you want the visual effect of 'gradually appearing' items:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync () 
{
    var temp =  new List<Vehicles>(); 
    // -> _vehicles being filled here

    _vehicles = new List<Vehicles>();
    foreach (var vehicle in temp)
    {
       _vehicles.Add(vehicle);
       StateHasChanged();
       await task.Delay(500);  // adjust the delay to taste
    }
}
```

but be aware that this is an expensive (slow) way to show them.
Using `@key` won't improve this but it might help when you change the list later:

```
 <VehicleComponent @key=vehicle Vehicle=@vehicle></VehicleComponent>
```

Comment: Task should be upper case:  await Task.Delay(500)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding the Render process.

Your Razor code gets compiled into a C# class with your Razor compiled as a `RenderFragment` (a delegate) - you can see it in the project `obj/Debug/Net5` folder structure.  The component "Render" events queue this delegate onto the Renderer's Queue.  The Renderer executes these delegates and applies changes to the Renderer's DOM.  Any changes in the Renderer's DOM get passed to the browser to modify it's DOM.

Henk's answer adds the items slowly to the list.  It adds a "Render" event through `StateHasChanged` and then yields through the `Task.Delay` to let the Renderer re-render the list on each iteration.